# Integer Divisions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, integer

```
n = int(input('Give a Number: '))
tambolenler = []

def tambolenleribul(n):
    for i in range(-100,n):
        if n % i == 0:
            tambolenler.append(i)
    return tambolenler
print(tambolenleribul(n))

        else:
            (n == 0)
        

print('n equal is zero')
```

hey guys. I wanna make this problem but I made a mistake ı guess.
I want to find the integer divisors for the number n entered.
There is a two condition.
First, n must be between -100 and 100.
Second, if n number is equal to zero, I want to print zero as output.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version with a non-optimal algorithm, but it should do the job:

```py
LOWER_BOUND = -100
UPPER_BOUND = 100


def find_divisors(n: int) -> list:
    """
    >>> find_divisors(8)
    [-8, -4, -2, -1, 1, 2, 4, 8]
    >>> find_divisors(-8)
    [-8, -4, -2, -1, 1, 2, 4, 8]
    >>> find_divisors(0)
    []
    """
    return [i for i in range(-abs(n), abs(n) + 1) if i != 0 and n % i == 0]


def main():
    n = int(input(f"Give a non-zero value between {LOWER_BOUND} and {UPPER_BOUND}: "))
    if n != 0 and LOWER_BOUND <= n <= UPPER_BOUND:
        print(f"The divisors of {n} are {find_divisors(n)}")
    else:
        print(f"{n} is not a valid input")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```